# Percona xtradb cluster 5.7 solution on AWS and on premise. Not all nodes are connected to

Tags: mysql, aws, galera, percona-server, xtradb-cluster

We have 3 nodes cluster. 2 in virginia and 1 in ohio. The cluster is working fine we do not have any issues. But nothing pop out when we started doing extensive monitoring using datadog. It shows that 1 node has barely a connection.
[image]

So I have logged into that one (172.11.15.18) and did some investigation

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                    | Value                                                 |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid           | 5af5510e-c901-11ea-b03f-f6de2f462cd7                  |
| wsrep_protocol_version           | 9                                                     |
| wsrep_last_applied               | 252354                                                |
| wsrep_last_committed             | 252354                                                |
| wsrep_replicated                 | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys                  | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes            | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes            | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_received                   | 14185                                                 |
| wsrep_received_bytes             | 7679813                                               |
| wsrep_local_commits              | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_replays              | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max       | 1                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg       | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max       | 3                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg       | 0.001198                                              |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto        | 238495                                                |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns     | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused        | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent          | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv          | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_flow_control_interval      | [ 173, 173 ]                                          |
| wsrep_flow_control_interval_low  | 173                                                   |
| wsrep_flow_control_interval_high | 173                                                   |
| wsrep_flow_control_status        | OFF                                                   |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance         | 5.984921                                              |
| wsrep_apply_oooe                 | 0.001948                                              |
| wsrep_apply_oool                 | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_apply_window               | 1.002020                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oooe                | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oool                | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_commit_window              | 1.000216                                              |
| wsrep_local_state                | 4                                                     |
| wsrep_local_state_comment        | Synced                                                |
| wsrep_cert_index_size            | 3                                                     |
| wsrep_cert_bucket_count          | 108                                                   |
| wsrep_gcache_pool_size           | 8232848                                               |
| wsrep_causal_reads               | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_cert_interval              | 0.003608                                              |
| wsrep_open_transactions          | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_open_connections           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_ist_receive_status         |                                                       |
| wsrep_ist_receive_seqno_start    | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_ist_receive_seqno_current  | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_ist_receive_seqno_end      | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses         | 172.10.15.25:4407,172.10.16.14:4407,172.11.15.18:4407 |
| wsrep_cluster_weight             | 3                                                     |
| wsrep_desync_count               | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_evs_delayed                |                                                       |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list             |                                                       |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency           | 0/0/0/0/0                                             |
| wsrep_evs_state                  | OPERATIONAL                                           |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid                 | d92a7dda-e842-11ea-89a1-5a4fd6ba61ba                  |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id            | 4                                                     |
| wsrep_cluster_size               | 3                                                     |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid         | 5af5510e-c901-11ea-b03f-f6de2f462cd7                  |
| wsrep_cluster_status             | Primary                                               |
| wsrep_connected                  | ON                                                    |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts            | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_index                | 2                                                     |
| wsrep_provider_name              | Galera                                                |
| wsrep_provider_vendor            | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                     |
| wsrep_provider_version           | 3.43(ra60e019)                                        |
| wsrep_ready                      | ON                                                    |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

From what I see from this, the cluster is fine but I can't shake off why the 3rd is not being used. I have done check process list on each of them and even opened all ports to the 2 networks just in case I have missed one port. I went and check the process list on the other 2 and they show 56 and 15 respectively. I am using java mysql driver and the connection string looks like `jdbc:mysql://172.10.16.14:4407,172.10.15.25:4407,172.11.15.18:4407/mydatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=ROUND&useSSL=false&failOverReadOnly=false` .

Not sure if I am missing a thing. Grateful if you can help clarify this.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-config-failover.html), the JDBC connector will use the servers listed in the connectstring in order, while always reattempting to connect to the server before it. So, if you have A,B,C and A goes down, the connector will use B and will continue to use B until A comes back up. When A comes back online, the connector will resume using A. C will only get used if both A and B are down.